# Valores que sofrem calculos, se armazena o valor com os calculos no banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, normalização

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde um produto sofre 3 alterações antes de chegar em seu valor final:
Desconto individual, Bonus de Venda e Desconto geral
Quero saber se, eu devo armazenar apenas o valor original do produto na base de dados ou se eu já faço todos os calculos relacionado a esse produto e então salvo o valor final dele.
Em meu caso, ainda se faria os calculos por diarias. Funcionaria como se fosse quantidade. Produto * diarias.
Por normalização de banco de dados, como seria o procedimento correto para persistir esses dados?

Comment: É informação , armazene separado.

Answer (score 1):

Você escolhe, se seu sistema está arquitetado para ter um processamento de banco de dados, então você pode já armazenar o valor final do produto, mas isso vai te impedir de saber quais foram os descontos logo de primeira (Você teria que desfazer os cálculos para isso).

Se você executar o cálculo antes de armazenar o valor e no final já armazenar ele descontado, você precisaria criar um campo na tabela para armazenar o valor original. Enquanto que se você armazenar o valor original você pode exibir o valor do desconto em uma view, mas o processo pode ser o inverso também.

Enfim, depende da sua arquitetura, o que você se sente mais confortável? Armazenar o valor original e depois descontar? Ou o contrário?

Comment: Ai minha questão vira outra. No caso de armazenar o valor original e os devidos descontos na base de dados, todas as vezes que eu precisar apresentar o valor desse produto, precisarei fazer os calculos na minha aplicação?

Comment: Então, depende do que você está usando, eu aconselharia o uso de views, elas pegariam os valores reais do produto e adicionariam em novas colunas nas quais o valor final seria calculado.